# Anime movie with two brothers, one has a sword which gets more powerful (but also more evil) when stones are added to it

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I watched an anime movie 4-8 years ago. Here's what I can remember:

It's about two brothers, they go to school. But the older brother has a sword and has to find gems/stones which make it more powerful. The younger brother wants him to stop (because of the evil that comes with that power I think).

Now I can't remember what was up with the stones at this point, but the brothers entered some kind of other world (it looked very bright I think) and had to fight, I THINK the older brother wanted to have the last stone which the younger one had.

I don't remember the ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two boys, one older, one younger, visiting another world where they compete for gemstones to upgrade their respecive weapons, and the younger one tries to stop the older one, not out of rivalry but to stop some evil? That much sounds exactly like [Brave Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Story#Plot). This story was made into an anime 2006, and released outside Japan in 2008.

The differences to your description: Wataru and Mitsoru from are not brothers, they are in different grades at the same school. Also only Wataru, the younger one has a sword, while the older Mitsuro is (at least in Vision, the other world) a magician and thus uses a staff.